# use namespace without url or uri .I'm confused

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm new to using XML , I'm learning the first concepts . I'm confused on the use of namespaces . I prepared two simple files: one xml-schema and XML document . please let help to understand the mistakes , if I have made ​​, and try to explain how to use the schema-file on my PC and not on a site. I ask this because all the examples I have found using a url like namespaces or location file.xml .
thank you.

P.S. sorry for my English

this is cdSchema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="CD"
xmlns="CD">
<xs:element name="artist" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="length" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="year" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="song">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="artist"/>
            <xs:element ref="length"/>
            <xs:element ref="title"/>
            <xs:element ref="year"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

this is compactDisc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CD xmlns="CD"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="CD cdSchema.xsd">

    <song>
        <artist>Santana</artist>
        <title>African Song</title>
        <length>4:42</length>
        <year>1993</year>
    </song>
    <song>
        <artist>Santana</artist>
        <title>Corazon Espinado</title>
        <length>4:36</length>
        <year>1996</year>
    </song>

</CD>
```

thanks for everybody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML specifications strongly encourage use of a URI as a namespace name, and it's good practice to use a URI within a domain that you own, for example `http://www.my-domain.com/ns/CD` (replacing your `CD`). This is to give a high level of confidence that your namespace will be unique. You don't actually have to have a web server at this address. It's a bit unfortunate really that people use the "http" scheme for namespaces, it might have been better to use `namespace://www.my-domain.com/CD` to make it clear we're not talking about resources accessible using HTTP; but for some reason, the convention of using "http:" has caught on.

Comment: OK thank you very much .
He's Saying That xml-schema instead of `targetNamespace = " CD"
xmlns = " CD"`
Can I use
`targetNamespace = " //www.miodominio.com/CD ​​"
xmlns = " // www.miodominio.com/CD ​​" ` and XML-doc
`xmlns = " // www.miodominio.com/CD ​​"
xsi : schemaLocation = " www.miodominio.com/cdSchema.xsd " `
Even if all this and invented ?

in practice I use it as a simple string without any logical reference

Comment: Well, yes. You can write a program and call all your variables by names like a, b, c, and x, and everything will work. But experienced software engineers will tell you that it's not a good idea.

Comment: ok thanks , give names to variables with logic is the basis of programming , says the naming convention . however it is not so difficult to create xml - doc but xml -schema concepts are not easy to learn . at least for me, I coming from an object oriented programming.

Comment: You advise me to study the xml -schema and not DTD?? I read that xml-schema is recommendation of W3C and i think that DTD is not used today

Comment: DTDs are still very widely used in the publishing industry, but not so much in other industry sectors.